# React - how to stop div onClick from changing sibling divs

Tags: css, reactjs, onclick, dom-events

I have 6 div elements that I want to be able to click one of and have the className change for just the div I've clicked on.  Currently, when I click on one div, ALL the div classNames change.  This idea came from a vanilla JS concept that I'm trying to convert into a React component.  I'm not sure where/what is going wrong, if anyone can tell me how to prevent the sibling divs' onClicks from being fired or if what I have is wrong fundamentally, I would be eternally grateful.  This is what I have so far:

```
import React, { useState} from "react";

import { Panels } from "../../components/index";
import { data } from "../../constants/index";
import "./gallery.css";


const Gallery = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggleOpen = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };
    
  return (
    <div className="panels">
      {data.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => (
        <div
          className={`panel panel${index} ${isOpen ? "open open-active" : ""}`}
          onClick={toggleOpen}
        >
          <Panels
            key={restaurant.name + index}
            description={restaurant.description}
            name={restaurant.name}
            website={restaurant.website}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

This is my Panels Component code:

```
import React from "react";

const Panels = ({ name, description, website }) => {
    return (
  <div className="panel_text">
    <p>{description}</p>
    <p>{name}</p>
    <a href={website}>
      <p>Visit {name}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
)};

export default Panels;
```

Aaaand this is my CSS code:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.panels {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.panel, .panel_text {
    background: '#fff';
    box-shadow: inse 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: var(--color-golden);
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition:
        font-size 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
        flex 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11);
    font-size: 20px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.panel0 {background-image: url(../../assets/defuegocarousel.jpg);}
.panel1 {background-image: url(../../assets/HaydenslakeSz.jpg);}
.panel2 {background-image: url(../../assets/stonecliffSz.jpg);}
.panel3 {background-image: url(../../assets/shigezooutside.png);}
.panel4 {background-image: url(../../assets/southparkSz.jpeg);}
.panel5 {background-image: url(../../assets/lechonoutside.jpg);}

.panel > * {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.panel > *:first-child {transform: translateY(-100%);}
.panel.open-active > *:first-child {transform: translateY(0); }
.panel > *:last-child { transform: translateY(100%); }
.panel.open-active > *:last-child {transform: translateY(0); }

.panel_text p, a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}

.panel p:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.panel.open {
    flex: 5;
    font-size: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .panel p {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving a **boolean** value as  a *div element* is open or not. So this value is considered for all *div element's* because there is no identifier which *div element* is open. You need to save a *div element* value to identify the open *div element*.

So you can use a *div element's* **index** instead of a boolean value. For example, try the below code.

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import { Panels } from "../../components/index";
import { data } from "../../constants/index";
import "./gallery.css";

const Gallery = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(null);
    
  return (
    <div className="panels">
      {data.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => (
        <div
          className={`panel panel${index} ${isOpen === index ? "open open-active" : ""}`}
          onClick={() => setIsOpen(index)}
        >
          <Panels
            key={restaurant.name + index}
            description={restaurant.description}
            name={restaurant.name}
            website={restaurant.website}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

Answer (score 0):

your isOpen state is common between all your div's
you should specify a unique value for isOpen of each div

you can change your isOpen state to an object like this :

```
import React, { useState} from "react";

import { Panels } from "../../components/index";
import { data } from "../../constants/index";
import "./gallery.css";


const Gallery = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState({});

    const toggleOpen = (index) => {
        setIsOpen(prevState => {...prevState ,[index]:!(!!prevState[index]) });
    };
    
  return (
    <div className="panels">
      {data.restaurants.map((restaurant, index) => (
        <div
          className={`panel panel${index} ${isOpen[index] ? "open open-active" : ""}`}
          onClick={()=>toggleOpen(index)}
        >
          <Panels
            key={restaurant.name + index}
            description={restaurant.description}
            name={restaurant.name}
            website={restaurant.website}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: The problem you identified was correct but I got errors about the prevState.  Thank you so much though!  Your answer definitely helped lead me in the right direction!!  You're incredible!